# Corruption of TLC plates or solvent

Tags: chromatography

I have been conducting TLC experiments, and sometimes I observed some lines when I use mixture of eluents.

[image: TLC line1]

And I found that some lines are observed after I develop the TLC plates with some eluents. And these lines are detectable via both 254 nm and 365 nm UV.

[image: TLC line2]

The plates might be corrupted when I cut it, so I test a small piece of unused plate. In this time I didn't develop the plate, rather immersed it quickly. Then the borderline was detected by UV. Even, the borderline turned yellow after it is immersed in methanol or ethyl acetate.

[image: TLC line3]

Are the plates corrupted due to long-term storage? These plates existed before I joined the lab, probably stored more than 2 years. I test the unopened solvents although they are stored for some periods after purchase.

Comment: I have noticed it in past regularly, if the eluent was mix of very polar minor solvent and much less polar major solvent. It seemed to me like imporities of solvent, plate sorbent binder or adsorbed  stuff over the time.